# Warning about global variables / module variables used in procedures?

Tags: fortran

I have an old Fortran code that I'm cleaning up. At this point I would like to get for each procedure a list of the variables that are not local: the code uses (abuses) global variables and I would like to get rid of so many references to global variables as possible. Doing it by hand is a pain, so I was looking for a compiler option to do this, but I couldn't find anything yet. Any pointers?

Thanks,
Ángel de Vicente

Answer (score 2):

I feel your pain.  Sadly, sympathy is almost all I have to offer, I haven't found an option for any of the Fortran compilers I've used recently (almost all of them in the last 6 years or so) which identifies them.

Tools such as [Understand for Fortran](http://www.scitools.com/) or [Fortran Lint](http://legacy.cleanscape.net/products/fortranlint/index.html) can help but they cost money; you might be able to download an evaluation copy without paying.

In the absence of such tools, I generally:

1. Comment out the variables I expect to be global, which generally means those declared in the program scope or passed around in common blocks
2. Slap `IMPLICIT NONE` around liberally, which you are probably doing anyway.
3. Get the compiler to spot undeclared variables in local scopes.

Comment: Hi, thanks. In the end I guess I don't have many choices then... Right now I'm using Emacs to compile only a region of a file (in my case a procedure), so that I will get errors for all host or use associated variables, but I was hoping there would be a more straightforward way to do it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

First use "implicit none" or an equivalent compiler option.  Hopefully you don't have too many undeclared variables.   Most compilers have an option which saves you adding "implicit none" to every procedure.  If there are no undeclared variables, go to the next step, otherwise declare them.  If there are too many undeclared variables, you are out of luck.  Then in a particular procedure comment out common blocks, include lines that are pulling in common blocks and module use statements.   See which variables become undeclared and generate a warning via "implicit none" -- that will disclose which variables in the common blocks and modules are actually used in that procedure.

If you have a module that includes both type declarations and variable declarations, this may not work. You might need to put the types and the declarations in separate modules so that you can comment out just the module with the variable declarations. But that's not likely with old code that abuses global variables.